# CSS selector for document

Tags: javascript, css, event-listener

How to select the document with selectors (JQuery, plain JavaScript etc...) ?

I'd like to trigger an event based on an event listener that listen when an user press Key 'Enter' (13) anywhere in the document.

I'm using this specific function to listen all events in my app :

```
export function listen(eventName, selector, handler) {
    document.body.addEventListener(eventName, event => {
        if(event.target.matches(selector)) {
            return handler(event);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a selector for that. You always have reference to it via `document`.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", handler);
```

If you want the `HTML` element, you can use the `"html"` selector.

```
document.querySelector("html").addEventListener(...)
```

Or just use `document.documentElement`.

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener(...)
```

---

And as [@cepharum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182819/cepharum) noted, you can do the same with jQuery by passing the element or selector to the `$` function.

---

Some notes on your updated question, while `document` is always available, `document.body` likely isn't until the body is fully loaded. You should be able to use `document` instead.

Also, you have a return statement in your event handler. That isn't going to do anything useful. The return value is ignored.

Finally, it doesn't seem like you want to limit the callback to a matching selector if it should be fired when the user presses the key anywhere in the document. That just seems like it'll interfere.

---

If you were hoping to do a selector-based event delegation, then you're almost there. You'll just most likely want to traverse up through the parent nodes of `event.target` to see which ones match the selector, and run then handler against them.

```
export function listen(eventName, selector, handler) {
    document.body.addEventListener(eventName, event => {
        var el = event.target;
        do {
          if (el.matches(selector)) {
            handler(event);
          }
        } while((el = el.parentNode));
    });
}
```

If you only want it to fire for the first match found, add `return` or `break` after the `handler` invocation.

Comment: Or use `$(document).on("click", handler)` when working with jQuery.

Comment: I edited my question, not really what I want to do, but thanks anyway

Comment: @dbrrt: Not sure what you mean. Seems like you want to capture that event anywhere in the `document`. Why do you think you need a selector for that? Are you actually trying to do a jQuery-like delegation? If so, there's an answer for that too, but you need to give details about what you truly want.

Comment: look at my edited question. I'm using the `listen` function to delegate the handling of event, based on selectors

Comment: @dbrrt: OK, so you're on the right track, except that it'll only delegate to selectors that match the `event.target`. If I understand what you want, you'll need to start at the `event.target`, and traverse up through the `.parentNode`s, checking the selector against each element. I can update with an example if you'd like.

Comment: I added an example. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for it, I'd rather avoiding editing the listen function, which can potentially as-is, be used by other services.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent modification to the generic function listen, I simply used 'body' as a selector.

```
listen('keypress', 'body', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    const todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput');
    todos.dispatch(addTodo(todoInput.value));
  }
});
```